# Changing the ID of all "div" elements (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I'm trying to change the ID of all elements with the tag "div". Here's my current script, which does not work:

```
function setIDs() {
    var divs[] = new Array();
    for(i in document.getElementsByTagName('div'))
        divs[i] = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];
    for(idNum in divs) divs[idNum].id="child"+idNum;
}
```

So after setIDs() is finished, my HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="child0">...</div>
<div id="child1">...</div>
...
<div id="childn">...</div>
```

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to do that? Also, describe "Does not work"

Comment: @Nevermind, still wrong.

Comment: @user1467611, a nice reference [why you shouldn't use for...in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/417685).

Comment: @Infotekka: Huh? The "id" attribute is read/write. Which browser quirks on that?

Comment: Ha, actually nevermind you are right - not sure where I got that from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`for...in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/417685) and reuse `document.getElementsByTagName` result.

```
function setIDs() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].id = "child" + i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this instead of "for in"

Answer (score 0):

Invalid JavaScript.

```
 var divs[] = new Array();
```

Also, do not use `for-in` for Array or Array-like iteration. It will often fail.

Comment: Pretty generalized on the whole 'it will often fail' answer. Could you please elaborate? if I'm iterating over the keys and indexes of an element then I cannot see any reason why `for...in` is not an acceptable method.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: `for-in` is for general property enumeration, irrespective of the property and its location in the prototype chain. All enumerable properties will be included in the loop. Running [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qRuMp/) in Firefox, you'll see more than just `div` elements in the console. Also it does not guarantee a sequential numeric order. Yes, my statement is generalized, and is meant to be. If index iteration is needed, `for-in` is very simply the wrong tool in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? If so, you should try something like this:

```
var x = 0;
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", "child"+x);
    x++;
});
```

Comment: that's not even how it should be with jQuery.

Comment: Working yes, but awful. Should be `$("div").attr(function(i){return "child"+i;});`

Comment: Sorry Bergi, your code doesn't work . And the question was tagged 'jQuery', that's why I allowed myself to answer like this. Anyway I'm not here to fight, so sorry if my answer bothered you.

Comment: oops, I missed the obvious: `$("div").attr("id", function(i){return "child"+i;})`

Comment: I don't see why this should have a down-vote (although using the index is nicer than an `x++`) so ... +1

Answer (score -1):

```
function setIDs() {
    var divs[] = new Array();
    // no need for an extra array. Invalid identifier, btw.

    for(i in document.getElementsByTagName('div'))
    // never run through Arrays with for-in-loops. It's the same for NodeLists.

        divs[i] = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];
        // you might have cached the NodeList to a variable

    for(idNum in divs) divs[idNum].id="child"+idNum;
    // again, don't use a for-in-loop. And why at all do you need a second loop?
}
```

corrected:

```
function setIDs() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].id = "child"+i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I use "for in" for arrays? It works in all browsers, it appears.

Comment: See [Why use a for loop instead of a for-in loop for arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6637240/1048572)